# Subselect with count, SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need to select the empno and the salary of all the female workers that in thier department are at least two male with the same salary like the female..

This is the tables

```
EMP:
empno|ename|deptno|sal|gender   
DEPT:
deptno|dname
```

This is my code, in some reason this dosent give the needed result

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP E
WHERE E.GENDER = 'F' AND 2 <= (SELECT COUNT(*)
                               FROM EMP E2
                               WHERE E2.GENDER = 'M' AND
                               E2.SAL = E.SAL
                               AND E.DEPTNO = E2.DEPTNO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select empno, sal
from emp e
where gender = 'F'
and exists (
  select 1
  from emp e2 
  where e2.gender = 'M' 
    and e.sal = e2.sal and e.deptno = e2.deptno
  having count(*) > 1)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7405/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
select e1.* 
from emp e1
join
(
    select sal, deptno
    from emp
    group by sal, deptno
    having count(distinct gender) = 2
    and sum(gender = 'M') >= 2
) e2 on e1.sal = e2.sal and e1.deptno = e2.deptno
where e1.gender = 'F'
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3786e/1)